# VBA Excel: Different colors in one line diagram depending on value

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm looking for a way to have three different colors in the same line chart of a diagram in Excel, depending on the values themselves or where they are from (from which sheet f.e).

Till now, I have the following code:

```
Sub ChangeColor()
Dim i As Integer
Dim IntRow As Integer
Dim r As Range

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Cash").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

IntRow = ActiveChart.ChartObjects("Cash").Count

For i = 2 To IntRow
    Set r = Cells(2, i)
    If r.Value < 3000 Then
        Selection.Border.ColorIndex = 5
    Else
        Selection.Border.ColorIndex = 9 
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

However, the if statement is not considered and the color of the whole line changes only whenever I change the first ColorIndex. I have no idea, how to color parts of the line depending on the values in the underlying table.

Moreover, by defining IntRow as `ActiveChart.ChartObjects("Cash").Count` I'm not able to get the length of my array. This problem can be solved by manual counting and declaring IntRow as an Integer, however, the version above seems nicer (if that is possible of course).

I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Alexandra

Answer (score 2):

You can read the values directly from the chart series:

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim cht As Chart, p As Point, s As Series
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numPts As Long

    'access the chart directly - no select/activate required
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Cash").Chart

    'reference the first series
    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1) 

    'how many points in the first series?
    numPts = s.Points.Count

    'loop over the series points
    For i = 1 To numPts

        Set p = cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)

        p.Border.ColorIndex = IIf(s.Values(i) < 3000, 5, 9)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I can try to do it that way. But what can I do If I need to refer to the cell itself? The point is, that I need to make the color of the line (parts of it) depending on from which sheet (I have a Forecast, a Plan and a Is-Status sheet) the number in the table (in each cell) comes from. Thats why I tried to refer to cells. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you want to identify the source range for a given series there's information on that here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?30968-Finding-data-range-reference-for-a-series-in-chart-using-vba